# WinError 193 %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to import these libraries in python using this code:

```
    import matplotlib as plt
    from matplotlib import style
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

I get this error when I start debugging

```
  Message=[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
  Source=C:\Users\basse\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\basse\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 2, in <module> (Current frame)
    import matplotlib as plt
```

These are the commands that I used in Visual Studio's terminal to install the libaries:

```
    pip install matplotlib
    pip install pandas
    pip install numpy
    pip install sklearn
    pip install pandas-datareader
    pip install beautifulsoup4
```

What should I do to solve this problem? Please consider that I'm kind of a beginner so make your answer detailed. Thanks!

Edit: I always get the same error with the 4 lines of code. For example, if the first line is `import pandas as pd`, I'll also get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `matplotlib`?

Comment: I reinstalled it, but the issue persists.